# Can you use two VR sets to play multiplayer on PS4?

Tags: ps4, playstation-vr

I bought a Playstation 4 with 2 controllers.
Recently I discovered a huge rental place for movies and games.

In it I saw they rent PS4 VR headsets.

I can rent two VR sets. Is it possible to use 2 VR sets in some kind of multiplayer? How would I do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is of course **No**.

You can check it on this link if you need to. **http://www.sonyrumors.net/2016/03/23/can-you-connect-two-playstation-vr-headsets-to-a-ps4/**